# Consulta sql server para borrar un ID y una COLUMNA

Tags: sql, sql-server

Esto me lo acabo de inventar y no funciona

```
    delete a.valor 
    from persona a 
    where a.Id = 3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo borra solamente el 555

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo por qué pensastes que sería necesario una sentencia `DELETE`. Pero toma en cuenta que el verbo en la sentencia aplica al registro, no a un campo individual. Y como tu intención no es borrar (`DELETE`) el registro, sino de *poner al día* el registro vaciando un campo, entonces el verbo que hay que usar es `UPDATE`:

```
update persona
   set valor = null
 where id = 3
```

Por supuesto, esto asume que tu columna `valor` está configurada para aceptar valores `NULL`.